# Finding an Object in a List

Tags: java, list, jsf

I have a List in a SelectOneMenu.
When the user selects one of this list, it gives me the value, not the label of it.
The thing I need is that label to display it on the screen. Is there a easier way to do it?

The way i'm doing right now is with a foreach like this:

```
for(SelectItem si : listOfSomething) {
 if (si.getValue().equals(myValue) {
  theLabelIs = si.getLabel();
  break;
 }
}
```

Maybe I didn't explain it well, so please tell me and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: generally labels are to show only.. we should use values for computation. I wonder why you are worried about label ?

Comment: He needs the label of selected item to display to users who may not make any sense out of the internal values.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Map` instead where item values are the map key and item labels are the map value.

```
private Map<String, String> options;

public Bean() {
    options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("value1", "label1");
    options.put("value2", "label2");
    options.put("value3", "label3");
    // ...
}
```

Then you can get it in the backing bean as follows:

```
String label = options.get(selectedValue);
// ...
```

or even in the view as follows

```xml
You have selected <h:outputText value="#{bean.options[bean.selectedValue]}" />
```

Comment: I've tried using it, but haven't found a way to use the map on the h:selectOneMenu.. Do you have any ideas of how to do it?

Comment: I assume that you're still on JSF 1.x? Since JSF 2.x it's supported. You need to populate a `List<SelectItem>` based on the mapping. You'd only use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` to maintain the insertion order.

Comment: I'm using JSF 1.2. But what I wonder is, if I'm going to populate based on the mapping, i'm still gonna have to read the whole map to build the List<SelectItem>. I was trying to find a way to stop reading the whole list.